# C++: Recommendations for Member Function Access at the Same Architecture Layer

Tags: c++, architecture

I have 4 classes of the following hierachy:

```
                     MyTop
                       |
              -------------------
              |        |        |
            BlockA   BlockB   BlockC
```

`BlockA`, `BlockB`, and `BlockC` are the composed objects of `MyTop`. `BlockA` provides a function `LookUpTable()`, and `BlockB` and `BlockC` now need to access the look-up table owned by `BlockA`. What is a good (or at least typical) practice for `BlockB` and `BlockC` to access the look-up table?

I thought about implementing the look-up table as a class itself, but the content of the loop-up table is slightly coupled with the initialization of `BlockA`, and it may not be trivial to decouple the table from `BlockA` (it's still doable, but not preferred). Right now my solution is to pass the request from `BlockB` and `BlockC` to `MyTop`, and let `MyTop` to manage the communication between the blocks. However, it doesn't seem a good way to handle the problem when there are more blocks that need access to the look-up table in `BlockA`. I wonder if this is a well-known problem and already has a "best practice" solution to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought about implementing the
>   look-up table as a class itself, but
>   the content of the loop-up table is
>   slightly coupled with the
>   initialization of BlockA, and it may
>   not be trivial to decouple the table
>   from BlockA (it's still doable, but
>   not preferred).

Can't you simply make BlocA intialize that look-up table owner object? It would be a singleton (if it's correct in your case) with BlocA as friend class to be sure it's the only one to access initialization (construction?) functions.

Comment: I think the table is a singleton. But how do I grant access of the table to `BlockB` and `BlockC`? (I am aware of the singleton pattern but never implement one myself.)

Comment: Simply provide a static function that give access to the unique instance. See this implementation for example : https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/3ca441c19bd8/OgreMain/include/OgreSingleton.h

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a general solution but there definitely is a general advice: [tell, don't ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask).

From what I can see you are trying to access the data of `BlockA` that is stored in a lookup table and then perform some operation on them. This is violation of the encapsulation principle where only the object holding the data should access and modify it.

A better way would be to extract the lookup table functionality into a class and add common methods for all three blocks. Then create three subclasses of the lookup table class and add methods that will be used only by specific blocks (if there are any such methods). In `BlockA`, `BlockB` and `BlockC` use these classes. This allows a more loose coupling than accessing a lookup table stored directly in `BlockA`.

Answer (score 0):

With the current mechanism, BlockB and BlockC consumes the facility provided in BlockA. My understanding is that it makes it different from BlockA. They are not on par.

BlockA, BlockB, BlockC inherits the methods of MyTop.

1. So LookUpTable() a method of MyTop.
2. It should access a object attribute which is initialized only when you instantiate BlockA.